# jquery - on("change", function() not working in IE 9

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am having some issues with a jquery on function that works in all browsers except IE.

jquery code is as follows:

```
$('#FormIndustryId, #FormIndustries').on("change", function () {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $.getJSON('/categories/list_categories/industry_id:' + $(this).val(),
    function (cats) {
      if (cats !== null) {
        populateCategorySelect(cats);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

From a front end point of view this can be tested here: http://www.beanclaim.com/ - there is a field with the label of **industry selection** which is the dropdown with #FormIndustries assigned to it, it should when an industry is selected update the second dropdown with the ajax content. Chrome, Firefox and Safari it works but it seems to do nothing in IE.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the ID is unique?

Comment: Try logging `$(this).val();`

Comment: I did not found any element with id FormIndustryId. Maybe the expression $('#FormIndustryId, #FormIndustries') return an empty array. Try to put only your #FormIndustries.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the ID is unique to the page. How would I log $(this).val()? (Sorry I don't do much javascript / jquery)

Comment: Changing it to $('#FormIndustries').on("change", function() instead of $('#FormIndustryId, #FormIndustries').on("change", function() still works in other browsers but not in IE 9. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because only in IE do you have this code execute:

```
// IF IE (BROWSER) USE jQUERY TO SET THE PLACEHOLDER
   // -------------------------------------------------->
    if ( $.browser.msie ) {
        $("#TemplateName").placeholder();
        $("#FormIndustries").placeholder();
    }
```

But, that returns this JS error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'placeholder'
```

and stops your JS from executing properly. I don't know what placeholder is (and neither does IE :) ), but if you fix that, the page works just fine in IE.

Comment: Thanks, this is was the issue. I hadn't included the placeholder script on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Write the same exact function, but make a copy using:

```
$('#FormIndustryId, #FormIndustries').on("click", ...
```